# HTACCESS doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are using wordpress multisite for a website.
We have some url that we need to redirect to new one.
We have tried few htaccess redirection but nothing work.

The last line is the redirection that we cannot make works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#redirect mobile browsers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/blog [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackBerry.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/blog [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Palm.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/blog [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourdomain.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=135
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/about-us/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Enable RewriteLog with RewriteLoglevel 9, the msgs will help in debugging better.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting those last 2 lines before the first rule, so you end up with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=135
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.ourdomain.co.uk/about-us/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't change anything:(
Im still staying on the same page.

Comment: Actually, it looks like your very first rewrite rule is catching it. Try putting it before the first one, like in my edit